# Windows 7 and WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, windows-7

When moved to Windows 7 platform a WCF call from ASP.NET project throws exception

```
  ex {"HTTP could not register URL http://+:9100/Jfc.Dealing.OrderProvider.BLClient.svc/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)."} System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException}

+  [System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException] {"HTTP could not register URL http://+:9100/Jfc.Dealing.OrderProvider.BLClient.svc/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)."} System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException

+  InnerException {"Access is denied"} System.Exception {System.Net.HttpListenerException}
  Message "HTTP could not register URL http://+:9100/Jfc.Dealing.OrderProvider.BLClient.svc/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details)." string
  Source "System.ServiceModel" string

+  TargetSite {Void OnOpen()} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that's from an outbound call? That is the error you get on Windows 7 (and Vista and Windows 2008) when you try to open a WCF "server" for listening. This happens if you attempt to create an endpoint without registering it. On the client it can happen if its a duplex service as, of course, the client then needs to open an endpoint.

The [KB article](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353) linked to in the exception has instructions on how to register an endpoint. Basically you run the following in an elevated command prompt.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=//+:9100/Jfc.Dealing.OrderProvider.BLClient.svc/ user=DOMAIN\Network Service
```

Replace DOMAIN with your machine name and it should be right for your machine.

Comment: I'm so used to ignoring those links in the exceptions that I didn't even think about trying that.  Your example worked great for me (except I couldn't get it to accept Network Service, so I used myself).  It's a shame I'll have to do this for every port I want to host a service on, though.

Comment: Ah what you can do then is to reserve a prefix and reserve something like //+9100/Ecyrb/ and then put each service on that port/Ecryrb so, for example http://localhost:9100/Ecyrb/Service1.svc/ and http://localhost:9100/Ecyrb/Service2.svc/

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you follow [the link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353) that is included in the exception and read what it says you have the answer. Run the command:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:9100
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue debugging my webservice in Visual Studio 2010.
I solved my issue launching Visual Studio 2010 using "Start as administrator."